# Integration of Sentiment analysis in CRM

Tags: machine-learning, python, sentiment-analysis

What is the process for integrating sentiment analysis in a CRM? What I am searching for is a system which analyzes the customer comments or reviews using the CRM and finds out the customer sentiment on the services provided by the system or company or a product.

I have done a sentiment analyzer which takes text and shows the sentiment of the text. Now I want to integrate the above-mentioned sentiment analyzer to a CRM, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of searching, I got one [paper](https://eprints.qut.edu.au/85084/1/Mohd%20Ridzwan_Yaakub_Thesis.pdf) on the integration of opinion mining in CRM, which helps to get an idea about the process involved.